# Terminology for a subtree of a rooted tree with a path boundedness property

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, trees

I'm not a graph theorist, so I apologize if some of the following terminology isn't quite correct.

Let $(T,f,v_0)$ be a complete degree $d$ rooted tree (definition at the end).

**Definition**. Let $m\ge0$. I'll say that a subtree $S\subset T$ has **Property $\boldsymbol m$** if for all vertices $v,w\in S$, the following implication holds:
$$
\text{($f^n(v)=f^n(w)$ for some $n\ge0$)}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
f^m(v)=f^m(w).
$$

I am interested in knowing:

1. Is there is a name for a subtree $S\subset T$  (that includes the
   root $v_0$) having Property $m$?
2. Is there a standard classification theorem or description for subtrees having Property $m$?

I've partially worked out the answer to (2), but would be happy to simply cite a result in the literature.

For example, if $S$ has Property $0$, then $S$ is what I think is called a branch of the tree.

**Definition**. A *complete degree $d$ rooted tree* is a triple $(T,f,v_0)$, where $T$ is a set of vertices, where $v_0\in T$ is the root vertex, where $f:T\setminus\{v_0\}\to T$ is a function that's used to define the directed edges $v\to f(v)$, and where $\#f^{-1}(v)=d$ for every vertex $v\in T$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T^n$ be a path with $2n$ edges rooted at its middle vertex.  If I understand your question correctly, then $S$ has **Property $m$** if and only if it does not contain $T^{m+1}$ as a rooted subtree.  Property $m$ can also be described globally, rather than forbidding local structure.  For example, $S$ has Property 1, if and only if it is a [Caterpillar_tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar_tree), where one end of the central path is the root $v_0$. Property $m$ can also be defined via generalizations of Caterpillar trees.  Namely, say that a tree is an *$m$-caterpillar* if all vertices are within distance $m$ of a central path.  Then $S$ has property $m$ if and only if $S$ is an $m$-caterpillar, where one end of the central path is the root $v_0$.